# Agregar una función dentro de una selección

Tags: javascript, html, funciones, select2

les agradeciería si me colaboran con esto: tengo una lista de opciones que representa las unidades del ejercicio, me gustaría que al seleccionar una está me arroje el resultado, en este caso mis selecciones son: Radianes y grados, es decir, que cuando seleccione radianes automáticamente el resultado me cambie a radianes y los mismo con los grados. Así como tengo el ejercicio, al dar clic en el botón azimut me arroja el resultado, pero ahora quiero que desplegando la lista igual me arroje el resultado pero teniendo en cuenta que el resultado de la opción radianes debe ser diferente al de grados pues están en unidades diferentes.

seria como esta en esta página: http://www.calculadoraconversor.com/arcotangente/

y el código lo tengo así

```js
function Azimut(){
 
 var E1= document.getElementById("E1").value;
 var N1= document.getElementById("N1").value;
 var E2= document.getElementById("E2").value;
 var N2= document.getElementById("N2").value;
  var Calculo_Azimut=(((Math.atan((parseInt(E2)-parseInt(E1))/(parseInt(N2)-parseInt(N1))))*180)/Math.PI);
  var Calculo_radianes=(Math.atan((parseInt(E2)-parseInt(E1))/(parseInt(N2)-parseInt(N1))));
 calAzi.value=Calculo_Azimut;
 calAzi2.value=Calculo_radianes;
}

  
</script>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilso.css"/>
<title>Taller_3</title>
</head>
  
  
  
 
  <body class="Fondo">


<div class="margen">
<div class="titulo">
<p>TALLER 3</p>
<p>Distancia Euclidiana (longitud), Punto medio, Azimut y Rumbo</p>
</div>


<div class="derecha">
<p class="a">Azimut</p>
<table class="tabla">
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Este</td>
<td>Norte</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>I</td>
<td><input type="text" name="E1" id="E1" placeholder="Ingrese Coordenada E1"></input></td>
<td><input type="text" name="N1" id="N1" placeholder="Ingrese Coordenada N1"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>II</td>
<td><input type="text" name="E2" id="E2" placeholder="Ingrese Coordenada E2"></input></td>
<td><input type="text" name="N2" id="N2" placeholder="Ingrese Coordenada N2"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br></br>
<input type="button" onClick="Azimut()" name="azi" id="azi" value="Azimut"> </input>
 <label for="calAzi"></label>
 <input type="text" name="calAzi" id="calAzi"> </input>
 <select id="lista_seleccion">
 <option id="calAzi2" >Radianes</option>
 <option id="calAzi">Grados</option>
 </select>
 
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo refactoriza tu código un poco. Por ejemplo, tu función puede recibir como parámetro el tipo de unidad en el que quiere hacer la operación:

```
// por defecto, radianes
function calc(unit = "radianes") {
  let e1 = document.getElementById("E1").value;
  let n1 = document.getElementById("N1").value;
  let e2 = document.getElementById("E2").value;
  let n2 = document.getElementById("N2").value;

  let result;

  if(unit === "radianes") {
    result = // fórmula radianes
  }
  if(unit === "grados") {
    result = // fórmula grados
  }

  document.getElementById("calAzi").value = result;
}
```

Ahora le añades un listener al select para que realize una opción cuando cambie:

```
<select onchange="calc(this.value)">
  ...
</select>
```

O si prefieres por medio de JavaScript:

```
let unitSelect = document.getElementById('lista_seleccion');
unitSelect.addEventListener('change', () => {
  let unit = this.value;
  calc(unit);
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, por otra parte te queria hacer un: pregunta: Con ese cambio como haria para hacer funcionar el boton nuevamente, pues ya cambio el nombre de la función de: Azimut() a calc(unit="radianes", es decir, como debo nombrar el Onclick para que con la nueva función me permita realizar el calculo, sin perder la función que me ayudaste a hacer.

Comment: listo amigo ya lo pude lograr, muchas gracias. Enserio fue de gran ayuda

Comment: De nada. Si te sirvió la respuesta, marcala como correcta. Saludos.